Name for design considerations when elements appear, disappear or move
I recently tried to hang up a Teams call but the other person in the call was quicker, and instead of hanging up, I clicked on the window behind it. There are also similar interactions with dialogues and windows that appear and a user that intents to click on something, instead click on the dialog or window that appeared on top. I can also imagine that moving elements have similar issues.
I'd like to learn more what the literature says about this but my searches does not come up with anything relevant. Is there an accepted name for these kinds of interactions?
I learned a long time ago that I should disable interactive elements for a short time when they appear without without user interactions. Are there other relevant the best practices?

Stuff that lets us know what's going to happen is called 'affordance'. Stuff that actions after we've clicked something (or the system is responding to something) is known as interaction choreography (in the case of say a mouse event) it's also called transition choreography and system orchestration (in the case of the app responding to events).
Material UI has some nice documentation on it. https://m2.material.io/design/motion/choreography.html#sequencing

This has happened to me multiple times with screen sharing button. I often term it to be 'I misclicked it'. Not sure if it is actually a terminology. In my observations it is because of the positions of one window behind the other or the movement of modals.
The other time I have experienced this is may be it is the alt+tab that I click or sometimes not, the focus of windows keep changing, not often but sometimes.
Your learning about disable interactive elements for short time is valid. In fact they work most of the time.
May be something like, do not focus on the newly opened window or previous window can make user consciously choose the window they want to interact with.
Some kind of feedback can be shown to the user. Something like a highlighted border or something that is visual before the action takes effect.
These were thoughts that came across.
